# How to add filter to check if database connection is stable before KafkaListener

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Trying to understand if there is an approach to have a filter before kafka listener. That filter should actually check for database connectivity, if the connection is stable then it should proceed with the kafka listener method else should not consumer any messages from the topic.

Comment: Why do you need this? If the consumer fails to write to the database, then it should fail and not commit those offsets. When the consumer starts again, it should start after the last successful write

Comment: We have an architectural pattern to send the failed messages to DEad Letter Queue but I want to avoid sending any database connection failures

Comment: If there's a database exception within your listener method, you have full control over not ack-ing that record. That's not a "filter"

Comment: I just want to avoid listening in the first place when there is an issue with the database like if database is down or any downstream is down

Comment: The below answer addresses that

Answer (score 0):

We can set `autoStartup = "false"` for the `@KafkaListener` annotation.

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "myContainer", topics = "myTopic", autoStartup = "false")
public void listen(...) { ... }
```

And then use `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` to start Kafka listener in the code:

```java
@Autowired
private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

...
// if (databaseService.isHealthy()) {
    this.registry.getListenerContainer("myContainer").start();
// }
...
```

Spring for Apache Kafka has the document about [@KafkaListener Lifecycle Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.6/reference/html/#kafkalistener-lifecycle).